# How to disable navigation menu on blogger posts?

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system, blogs, blogger

I want the navigation menu to be visible only in the blog's home page, and to be hidden in posts.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to provide more details when asking here questions.
Which blog? Do you have a link? Do you have some HTML to share? Can you create JSFIddle for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Blogger.com to your blog then Template > Edit HTML and enclose the code of the navigation menu within the following conditional code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.homepageUrl == data:blog.url'>
 ...
</b:if>
```